# Исключение: Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

На строке First[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100); выдает исключение "Индекс находится вне границ массива"

```
public class Massiv
        {
            public static int n = 0;
            public double[,] First = new double[n, n];
            public double[,] Second = new double[n, n];
            public double[,] Third = new double[n, n];
            public double Max;
            public double Maximum(int j)
            {
                double Maxim = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (Second[i,j] > Maxim)
                    {
                        Maxim = Second[i, j];
                    }
                }
                return Maxim;
            }
            public void NaMasse(ListBox lb)
            {
                lb.Items.Clear();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                rnd.NextDouble();
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0;j < n; j++)
                    {
                        First[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
                        Second[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
                    }
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        Third[i, j] = First[i, j] * Maximum(j);
                    }    
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    string s = " ";
                    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        s += Third[i, j].ToString("F2") + "   ";
                    }
                    lb.Items.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Massiv ma = new Massiv();
            Massiv.n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            ma.NaMasse(listBox1);
        }
```

Comment: Запихните инициализацию массивов в конструктор и передавайте n в конструктор.

Comment: Вы не задали вопрос.

Comment: Вы объявляете `int n = 0;` и создаёте массив с нулевыми размерами: `First = new double[n, n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаёте ma через вызов `new Massiv()` у вас УЖЕ создаются массивы `First`, `Second` и `Third` и размер их - ноль, т.к. `n` ещё не задана.

Вот посмотрите что под отладчиком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы ещё не дошли до присвоения `n`, а массивы уже есть и их размер не 4, а ноль. После присвоения `n = 4` их размер так и останется ноль.

Поэтому передавайте `n` в конструктор, а затем аккуратно инициализируйте правильным значением:

```
public class Massiv
{
    private int n = 0;

    public double[,] First;
    public double[,] Second;
    public double[,] Third;

    public Massiv(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;

        First = new double[n, n];
        Second = new double[n, n];
        Third = new double[n, n];
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]